# The Cluster refresh solution

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

> Update: We are using AIX environment.

We have been facing some random issues with our queues (cluster queues), like:

> 1. 2189 Cluster resolution error (Most frequent one)
> 2. 2270 MQRC_NO_DESTINATIONS_AVAILABLE
> 3. 2053 Queue full error(Weirdest) : Post one message, it will be successfully posted, post some 3-4 messages, it will throw this error
>      for the rest of the messages.

**All these issues get resolved once we do a cluster refresh**. But, I want to know the root cause, why we get these errors. What goes wrong?

How cluster refresh resolve these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a socket issue. You can monitor sockets according to your OS - like on windows can do

```
 netstat -a -b -o >/newfile.txt
```

You could also use TCP Viewer on windows (one exe from Microsoft/ sysinternals) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx actually all the sys internal toos should be in your prod box if windows.

For sockets in linux/Un* there are other tools, some just ls commands into the RAM, depending on the version. Maybe a google will help.

Also if using windows consider moving some stuff to linux, you will have some pain in the beggining but will get better.

If this did not help you should post yor environment on your quesiton and give any other details. And if you get a jprofiler into production and use it when the issue happens.

At the very least you can do a jstack and jmap

What is version/ name of OS and of java, websphere?

If it is a socket issue can try increasing sockets (registry) and then profiling your code to see who  is making  too many sockets, what needs to be throttled or re-written.

Remember every page, every db connection, external cache hit (if you use) or any other URL work/ remote connection is usually a socket.

Comment: well you can google how to monitor sockets in that OS. jstack and jmap will work the same. you can google how to read that and then come back here if you have specific questions after you analyze data from these tools. but just saying cluster goes bad and restart helps is not very useful. you should also profile apps in UAT if not production (UAT :with as similar config and traffic patterns)